# Possible to Return a Bool Value When Attempting to Insert Into SQLite Database?

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, sql-insert, sequel

I created an SQLite database from the command line with the the columns: title, date, url and location. Then I added a unique constraint on title, date, url and location with the goal that this would prevent identical rows from being inserted.

I inserted the first batch of data and it worked perfectly. To test the unique constraint I attempted to re-insert all the data that and got a:

```
...SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: events.title...
```

error as expected.

However, I don't want the program to stop running should an insert fail, rather I want it to return a Bool so I can increment a variable called new events when inserts are successful.

Do I need to change how I setup my database or is there a way of doing this?

Incidentally I am using Ruby and Sequel.

Here's the source code for the insert

```
    newEventCount = 0
    events.each do |event|
        result = eventDB.insert(:title => event.get_title, :date => event.get_date, :url => event.get_url, :location => event.get_location)
        if result == false
            puts "Already have it"
        else
            newEventCount = newEventCount + 1
        end
    end
```

Any and all guidance is deeply appreciated and please forgive my ignorance if this question seems completely obtuse. Working with databases is very new to me.

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a way to catch exceptions? The only way I can think of to have the database return false rather than throw an exception would be to trap it within a stored procedure that did the insert, but sqlite doesn't do stored procedures as far as I know.

Comment: Apparently ruby does indeed have a way to handle exceptions. @tadman explains it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `false` means errors can be ignored, plus it means propagating those errors can require a lot of work. Exceptions bubble up automatically, and if they get to the top this is what happens: Your program crashes.

The way to mitigate this is to handle the exception:

```
events.each do |event|
  begin
    eventDB.insert(
      title: event.get_title,
      date: event.get_date,
      url: event.get_url,
      location: event.get_location
     )

     newEventCount += 1
  rescue SQLite3::ConstraintException
    # Already inserted, can be ignored.
  end
end
```

That pattern of rescuing a very specific, expected exception is often necessary.

Comment: Ahhhh I see! That makes perfect sense! Thanks so much @tadman !